# Longest gap between test matches in Sachin's career

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL server and was practising using Sachin's batting stats (Cricket) I found here. ([Sachin Batting Statistics](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/35320.html?class=11;home_or_away=1;home_or_away=2;home_or_away=3;orderby=start;orderbyad=reverse;template=results;type=allround;view=innings)). I wanted to find the longest gap between two test matches in Sachin's career. So basically have to filter it based on Test matches and find the max difference in the Start_DateAscending column? Hope that made some sense. [Sample table added if link doesn't make sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU4Fg.png)

EDIT: I created a sample table with different dates. the column is named DateValues. Now, I want to find the code for maximum difference between any two successive rows in the DateValue column. For example, in this case the answer is 2 years and 17 days between December 09, 1989 and December 26, 1991

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#mytable','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #mytable


CREATE TABLE #mytable 
        (
        ID    INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        DateValue  DATETIME
        )

SET DATEFORMAT DMY

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #mytable ON

INSERT INTO #mytable 
       (ID, DateValue)

SELECT '11', 'Nov 15 1989 12:00AM' UNION ALL    
SELECT '59', 'Nov 23 1989 12:00AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '37', 'Dec 09 1989 12:00AM' UNION ALL    
SELECT '44', 'Dec 26 1991 12:00AM' UNION ALL    
SELECT '55', 'May 31 1993 12:00AM' UNION ALL    
SELECT '60', 'May 15 1995 12:00AM' UNION ALL    
SELECT '57', 'Jan 12 1996 12:00AM' UNION ALL    
SELECT '43', 'Jan 19 1996 12:00AM' UNION ALL   
SELECT '49', 'Jan 31 1996 12:00AM' UNION ALL    
SELECT '18', 'Oct 17 1997 12:00AM'
```

Here's a solution I found on this website, the answer I obtained was 1900-01-01!

```
SELECT MAX(#mytable.DateValue-h.DateValue) as maxDiff 
FROM #mytable
LEFT JOIN #mytable h 
ON h.ID=[dbo].#mytable.ID AND #mytable.DateValue>=h.DateValue
WHERE h.DateValue IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [Forum Etiquette: how to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). Have a look at these links, and edit your question. We aren't here to do all the work for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question doesn't show much research and doesn't include a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Usually with SQL questions, it's best to include something we can copy/paste into SQL Server Management Studio to recreate your data, rather than just an image of the data. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: I apologize for my mistake, I will make sure not to do the same thing twice. I am adding a code that I found on this website to the question, that's all I have, but I know for sure that the answer is wrong but not sure why. Also, my data is on a csv file and I am still trying to figure out how to upload that so you can copy/paste to your ssms

Comment: Thanks for improving your question, I've written an answer based on it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or above, this SQL will return the biggest gap in days between two tests:

```
select max(datediff(day, a.TestDate, a.NextTest)) as BiggestGap
from (
    select DateValue as TestDate, lead(DateValue) over (order by DateValue) as NextTest
    from #mytable m
) a
```

The first thing this query does (inside the parenthesis) is gets a table that lists all test matches and the date of the next test match. That's what the innermost query provides: It selects all test dates and, using the [`lead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) function, the date of the match straight after that test.

The data from that parenthesised select (including ID) looks like this:

```
ID          TestDate                NextTest
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
11          1989-11-15 00:00:00.000 1989-11-23 00:00:00.000
59          1989-11-23 00:00:00.000 1989-12-09 00:00:00.000
37          1989-12-09 00:00:00.000 1991-12-26 00:00:00.000
44          1991-12-26 00:00:00.000 1993-05-31 00:00:00.000
55          1993-05-31 00:00:00.000 1995-05-15 00:00:00.000
60          1995-05-15 00:00:00.000 1996-01-12 00:00:00.000
57          1996-01-12 00:00:00.000 1996-01-19 00:00:00.000
43          1996-01-19 00:00:00.000 1996-01-31 00:00:00.000
49          1996-01-31 00:00:00.000 1997-10-17 00:00:00.000
18          1997-10-17 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

After that (outside the parenthesis), it's simply a case of finding the row with the biggest difference between dates. In SQL Server, it's best to use the [`datediff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) function to get the difference between two dates instead of using mathematical operators such as `-` in the example you saw, so we use that to get the difference in days between each row. `max` is used to get the largest of those, thus returning the biggest gap between two matches.

Using the example SQL data provided, the biggest gap is 747 days (approximately 2 years 17 days).